# awk: Is possible to change the FS variable in block code in an awk script?

Tags: variables, awk, scripting, fs

any help is appreciated.

I have the following lines in "csv" file:

```
11;juan;planA|2014-06-02|3853157|-,planb|2014-08-15|-|-;11111111

12;andrew;planA|2014-07-20|-|-;22222222
```

I need to produce the following output:

---

account=11

```
 Name=juan
 Phone=11111111
 Plan=planA
 Expire=2014-06-02
 used=3853157
 free=
 Plan=planB
 Expire=2014=08-15
 used=
 free=
```

account=12

```
 Name=andrew
 phone=22222222
 Plan=planA
 Expire=2014-07-20
 used=
 free=
```

My awk script to print the first 3 lines is very simple:

```
BEGIN { FS=";";
}
{
print("account=")$1;
print("name=")$2;
print("phone=")$4;       

}
END {
}
```

So, I need some lights to produce the logic for the "plan info" lines:

I could to assign the field $3 to $0 variable to have a complete new line only for the field 3, and change the FS (File Separator) to "," to split the plans. Then again assign the $1 to $0 and change the FS now to "|" to have the field to print the plan lines.

What I need to know is if it possible to change the FS variable in the block code section..or am I totally wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use split for that..

Comment: If at all possible, change the input file format to something sane. Whoever designed that file format should be publicly shamed.

Comment: @tripleee: why? That's a classic multi-level scheme which has the advantage that `$4` is _always_ the same data item. PICK/Revelation (though dated) did this with its multi-values, ASCII has different levels of separators (FS/RS/US/GS) and so on. By the way, user3717197, FS is field separator rather than file separator but we get the idea :-)

Comment: Because it is pesky to understand and manipulate, and impossible to extend. In this day and age, structured, vaguely self-documenting formats like JSON would be a natural choice. Obviously, back in the day, they had not been invented yet.

Comment: Although JSON may well be easier for _humans_ to understand (without extra doco), I suspect the `awk` code to process it would be substantially more complicated :-) And "impossible" is a rather strong word, you can extend the scheme quite easily in all dimensions (at least until you run out of separator characters). It depends, i suspect, on what is expected to _use_ the data (people, simple programs, complicated programs with JSON libraries built in and so on).

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to mess about with the field separator, `awk` gives you similar functionality by using `split` on a field to get an array, such as with:

```
split($3,f3,"|");
```

The following transcript shows this in action:

```
pax> echo "x1;x2a|x2b|x2c;x3" | awk -F';' '{split($2,arr,"|");print $1" "arr[2]}'
x1 x2b
```

Your *specific* case is a little more complex since you need to split `$3` into plans and then, for *each* of those plans, split to extract the four pieces of information. The following script seems to work okay for that:

```
BEGIN {FS = ";"}
{
    print "Account="$1
    print "  Name="$2
    print "  Phone="$4
    nplans = split ($3, plans, ",")
    for (i = 1; i <= nplans; i++) {
        split (plans[i], planinfo, "|")
        if (planinfo[3] == "-") { planinfo[3] = "" }
        if (planinfo[4] == "-") { planinfo[4] = "" }
        print "  Plan="planinfo[1]
        print "    Expire="planinfo[2]
        print "    Used="planinfo[3]
        print "    Free="planinfo[4]
    }
}
```

outputting:

```
Account=11
  Name=juan
  Phone=11111111
  Plan=planA
    Expire=2014-06-02
    Used=3853157
    Free=
  Plan=planb
    Expire=2014-08-15
    Used=
    Free=
Account=12
  Name=andrew
  Phone=22222222
  Plan=planA
    Expire=2014-07-20
    Used=
    Free=
```

Comment: I also thought in same direction…Nice!

Comment: Use `for (i=1;i in f3;i++)` instead of `for (i in f3)` if you want the order of the plans in the output to be guaranteed to be the same as the input order. Not sure `f3` and `f3x` are great variable names (why not `plans` and `plan` or similar?) but +1 for the approach! Oh and the 3rd arg for `split()` is an RE and so when a constant should be delimited by `/`s not `"`s and all those trailing semi-colons are redundant.

Comment: All good points, @Ed, I've incorporated some of your suggestions. For the third arguments, I simply prefer the quotes when I'm using a single character and, being a C bigot, I like the semicolons :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use regular expressions to separate fields:

```
awk -F'[;|,]' '{i=1;
            print "account="$i;i++;
            print "Name="$i;i++;
            print "Phone="$NF;
            while(i < NF){
              print "Plan="$i;i++;
              print "Expire="$i;i++;
              print "used="($i!="-"?$i:"");i++;
              print "free="($i!="-"?$i:"");i++;
            }
            print "";}' input.txt
```

Which at least works for your sample input. I assumed there is no blank lines in the sample input.

Output:

```
account=11
Name=juan
Phone=11111111
Plan=planA
Expire=2014-06-02
used=3853157
free=
Plan=planb
Expire=2014-08-15
used=
free=

account=12
Name=andrew
Phone=22222222
Plan=planA
Expire=2014-07-20
used=
free=
```

Input:

```
11;juan;planA|2014-06-02|3853157|-,planb|2014-08-15|-|-;11111111
12;andrew;planA|2014-07-20|-|-;22222222
```